# jquery tries to slide an already open div, creates a 'bounce' effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks in advance for any one who reads/offers a solution.

I'm currently rebuilding my portfolio site but running into a small issues that isn't site-breaking, but without it properly built, are unpleasing to the eye.

**Issue**: When a user clicks on a project, the description slides down from being hidden.  When a user clicks on another project on the same row it basically tries to close the current project then opens the new project quickly, for half a second, the project starts to hide, then expands again, creating an interesting 'bounce' like effect.

Ideally I want any project on the same row to just display, without changing the height at any point.

Code: 
HTML

```
<section class="personal">
<header class="header">
 <nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-bar">
   <li><a class="p" href="#">p</a></li>
   <li><a href="mailto:im@pbj.me" data-icon="a"></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.github.com/patrickbjohnson" target="_blank" data-icon="g"></a>     </li>
   <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/patrickbjohnson" target="_blank" data-icon="t"></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
<h1>Johnathan Doesmith</h1>
<h2>Cras Purus Quam</h2>
<h3>Cras purus</h3>
</section>

<section class="work">
<ul>
<li class="project">
 <img src="img/image1.jpg">
 <a href="#">Project Name</a>
 <div class="description">
  <h1>Project Name 1</h1>
  <h2>Project website</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec sed odio dui. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
  <button>visit site</button>
 </div>
</li>
<li class="project">
 <img src="img/image1.jpg">
 <a href="#">Project Name</a>
 <div class="description">
  <h1>Project Name 1</h1>
  <h2>Project website</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec sed odio dui. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
  <button>visit site</button>
 </div>
</li>
<li class="project">
 <img src="img/image1.jpg">
 <a href="#">Project Name</a>
 <div class="description">
  <h1>Project Name 1</h1>
  <h2>Project website</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec sed odio dui. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
  <button>visit site</button>
 </div>
</li>
<li class="project">
 <img src="img/image1.jpg">
 <a href="#">Project Name</a>
 <div class="description">
  <h1>Project Name 1</h1>
  <h2>Project website</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec sed odio dui. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
  <button>visit site</button>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.project > a').click(function(event){

    // variables
    var $this = $(this);
    var $project = $('.project');
    var $target = $project.filter($this.parent());

    // stop link jump from happening
    event.preventDefault();
    // $target.addClass('open') *****

    // removes 'open' class from all elements except
    // for the parent ('li') of the clicked element
    $('.open').not($target).removeClass('open');


    if ($target.hasClass('open')) {
        // if the target has the class, remove it. 
        $target.removeClass('open');
        // what is 'return false supposed to do in this instance?'
        return false;
    } else {
        // if the target doesn't have the class, then add it. 
        $target.addClass('open');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Site is also live here: http://www.pbj.me/dev/pbj/v3

Answer (score 0):

Jquery: instead of bounce, use fade in.

set the height on a parent div and then set the .fadeIn(1000) on a child div.
dynamically, when each is clicked.

```
<style>
div.parent{height:50px; width:100%;}
div.child{height:100%; width:100%;}
</style>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Project Information</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(".child").css("display", "none");
  $(".child").fadeIn(1000);
</script>
```

Now all you need to do is set the script bits inside a your click event

Dont forget to wrap all script in a ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Ps, your images are crazy big, make them smaller and optomise them for the web.
Otherwise this will seriously affect you page loading time and make javascript run like a pig.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're removing the `.open` class from your `$('.open').not($target)` elements, it triggers the transition animation slightly before your new `$target` opens.

I think you'll have to close the existing windows differently, based on whether or not they live in the same row.  Are you always going to have only 2 `<li>` elements per row? If so you can use a conditional like such:

var previouslyOpenIndex = $('.open').not($target).index(;
var targetIndex = $target.index()

```
if (( targetIndex % 2 === 0 && previouslyOpenIndex == targetIndex + 1) || (previouslyOpenIndex % 2 ===0 && targetIndex == previouslyOpenIndex + 1)) {
   // Descriptions are on the same row

}
```